# MongoDB Error: "Subclass must implement GetDocumentID" when trying to insert List<string>

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to add a simple list of strings:

```
string[] misc = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
List<string> myList = new List<string>(misc);
mongo_collection.Insert(myList);
```

And it will return the error: "Subclass must implement GetDocumentID"

I tried this instead:

```
mongo_collection.InsertBatch(myList);
```

but it resulted in the same error. There has to be a way to insert this without creating a new class that inherits from List that implements GetDocumentID, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think there has to be a way to do that?  How would you retrieve the list of strings after you put it into the `mongo_collection`?

Comment: I would think that it would create a sub-list (sorry, my mongodb terminology knowledge-base is still pretty green) within my document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to put a List of type String into a mongo database.  In order to add something to Mongo, it either has to be a Bson Object or you have to create a custom object, and map the properties so the Mongo knows how to convert your object into BSON.

Comment: To supplement the answer, you need to create a BsonDocument and add a BsonArray into it (with a corresponding key). You can refer to the docs for more details: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-TheBSONLibrary

Answer (score 1):

The top level object being inserted into a collection must be an object that maps to a BSON document (not a BSON array).

Also, the top level object must always have an Id field (which maps to an element named _id).

To insert your data to the database you would define a class something like this:

```
public class C
{
    public ObjectId Id;
    public List<string> Strings;
}
```

and then you can insert the data like this:

```
var document = new C();
document.Strings = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
collection.Insert(document);
```

Note that the Id will be assigned a value automatically (as long as the Id is of a type like ObjectId that supports automatic generation of unique values).